Minimal APIs in Blazor with RequireAuthorization() using Individual Account
In my .NET 8 Blazor project, I added the "Individual Account" to manage users. The application has 2 projects.
Server
The server side contains the login part and the controllers/endpoints.

The controllers/endpoints are minimal APIs like this one
public static void MapClientEndpoints (this IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
{
    var group = routes.MapGroup("/api/Client").WithTags(nameof(Client));

    group.MapGet("/", async (HypnoContext db) =>
    {
        return await db.Client.ToListAsync();
    })
    .RequireAuthorization()
    .WithName("GetAllClients")
    .WithOpenApi();
}

in order to save in the database. Also, I added the configuration for HttpClient:
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
    PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => 
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddSignInManager()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services
    .AddScoped(sp => sp
        .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient("ServerAPI"))
        .AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", (provider, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder. Configuration["FrontendUrl"]);
        });

Client
The client project has all the views. The views call the APIs provided by the server.

In the Program.cs this configuration is added out of the box:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
    PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();

In order to connect to the APIs from the pages, I created a class to group all the calls in a single place. The constructor is this
string baseEndpoint;
IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory;
HttpClient? httpClient;

public ApiService(string baseUrl, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    baseEndpoint = baseUrl;
    ClientFactory = clientFactory;
    httpClient = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");
}

Although I log in to the application as a user, the calls to the APIs work only if no authorisation is required in the Minimal API. It is like that the IHttpClientFactory doesn't have the
How can I protect the APIs and use them from the client side?
What I tried
In the Program.cs of the server, I added this code for the HttpClient:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["FrontendUrl"]);
    })
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddTransient(sp =>
    sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

The CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler is as follows
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
           authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7241" });
    }
}

I'm doing this because I want to make calls to the APIs exposed in the server project protected by the Individual Account. So, in a page
@inject HttpClient httpClient

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Client");
await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

When I run the application, I immediately get an error:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be
constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
'ServiceType: MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler
Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType:
MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler': Unable to resolve
service for type
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider'
while attempting to activate
'MyApp.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.)'



Hi @Enrico, I have created a .NET 8 Blazor App with Individual account, and it can access "api/client" if i login successfully.  Can you explain you code more detailed with the project structure and location of the code?

I reorganized my post. Let me know if this is clear @Rena. Thank you in advance for your help

Hi @Enrico, did your server and client project are separate?

Yes, as I wrote in the post.

Hi @Enrico, did your two project contains custom AuthenticationStateProvider?The server project calls PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider, while the client project calls PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider.

Yes, I have that. I updated the post for future reference.

Hi @Enrico, it seems your project structure is the same as mine. I have shared a whole working code for you. Besides, as my previous answer said, do not use custom AuthorizationMessageHandler in your project.

First of all I need to say the correct result should be : No matter you login with authorized user or not, you will always get 200 result, because if you do not authorize successfully, it will redirect to Login page with 200 result.
For how to check the authorization work or not: You need set breakpoint to the minimal api endpoint to check if the request send to it. If the user are not authorized, it will never hit the minimal api endpoint.


Please follow my steps to check your project:
HypnoPlatform Project
1.controllers folder contains static class like below
public static class ClientEndpoint
{
    public static void MapClientEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
    {
        var group = routes.MapGroup("/api/Client");

        group.MapGet("/", async (ApplicationDbContext db) =>
        {
            return await db.Users.ToListAsync();
        })
        .RequireAuthorization()
        .WithName("GetAllClients").WithOpenApi();
    }
}

2.Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender<ApplicationUser>, IdentityNoOpEmailSender>();


builder.Services
    .AddScoped(sp => sp
        .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient("ServerAPI"))
        .AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", (provider, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7216");
        });
var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp1.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
ClientEndpoint.MapClientEndpoints(app);   //be sure register the api
app.Run();

HypnoPlatform.Client Project
1.call HttpClient in razor component(for easy testing, I use Counter.razor)
@page "/counter"
@inject HttpClient httpClient
    
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    HttpMethod.Get, "/api/Client");
        await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}

2.Program.cs(You also need register the Httpclient in HypnoPlatform.Client project)
Note: Do not use builder. Configuration["FrontendUrl"] like HypnoPlatform Project do, because there is no appsettings.json in HypnoPlatform.Client project.
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services
    .AddScoped(sp => sp
        .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
        .CreateClient("ServerAPI"))
        .AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", (provider, client) =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7216");
        });
await builder.Build().RunAsync();


No matter the authorization pass or not, you will always get 200 result, because if you do not authorize successfully, it will redirect to Login page with 200 result. You need set breakpoint to the minimal api endpoint to check if the request send to it to check the authorization work or not. If you are not authorized, it will never hit the minimal api endpoint.
